# How do I add a value to all rows in a column if the column name contains a specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame that looks like this:

| City | Cars | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Madrid | 550000 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| London | 783993 | 1 | 3 | 0 |

I want to add +1 to all of the columns that contain 'Col' in their title. So the df looks like this:

| City | Cars | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Madrid | 550000 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| London | 783993 | 2 | 4 | 1 |

My issue is that I have 2000 columns with names from 'Col_1' to 'Col_999'

I was only able to add +1 to all of the columns by using `df["Gene1"] = df["Gene1"] + 1`
This is unsuitable because I have 2000 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```py
df[[col for col in df if col.startswith('Col')]] += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
df = df.filter(like="Col")

#or 

df = df.filter(regex='Col')
```

then,

```
df+1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option:

```
df = df.assign(**df.filter(regex='^Col').add(1))
```

Output:

```
     City    Cars  Col 1  Col 2  Col 3
0  Madrid  550000      1      1      3
1  London  783993      2      4      1
```